# NSAttributedString: Setting FontAttributes doesn't change font

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsattributedstring, foundation

I am trying to change the font on an NSAttributedString.

I have a method which iterates over each character, and creates a new NSFontAttribute dictionary for that character. In the end, however, the string remains un-changed. To demonstrate, here is how I setup the string:

```
UIFontDescriptor *fontDescriptor = [UIFontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithName:@"Avenir-Book" size:14.0f];

 NSDictionary *fontAttributes = [fontDescriptor fontAttributes];

 [fontAttributes setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u",[fontDescriptor symbolicTraits]] forKey:UIFontSymbolicTrait];

 [mutableAttributedString setAttributes:fontAttributes range:(NSRange){0,length}];
```

This produces the following NSFontAttribute dictionary for the entire string:

```
Font Attributes: {
    NSCTFontSymbolicTrait = 2147483648;
    NSFontNameAttribute = "Avenir-Book";
    NSFontSizeAttribute = 14;
}
```

I go through and modify each character's FontAttribute to add bolding or italics, as follows:

```
for (int i = (int)range.location; i < (range.location + range.length); i++){
    /* Extract Font Attributes */
    NSDictionary *extractedAttributes = [[mutableAttributedString attributesAtIndex:i effectiveRange:NULL]mutableCopy];

    /* Determine New Trait */
    uint newTrait = ((uint)[[extractedAttributes valueForKey:UIFontSymbolicTrait]longLongValue] | [self symbolicTraitForMarkdownType:markdown]); // (markDown  is a mask)

    /* Set New Trait */
    [extractedAttributes setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u",newTrait] forKey:UIFontSymbolicTrait];

    /* Create New Font Descriptor */
    UIFontDescriptor *newDescriptor = [UIFontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithFontAttributes:extractedAttributes];
    newDescriptor = [newDescriptor fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:newTrait];

    /* Apply Font Descriptor */
    [mutableAttributedString setAttributes:[newDescriptor fontAttributes] range:(NSRange){i,1}];
}
```

This produces many different FontAttributes:

```
Index 1: {
    NSCTFontSymbolicTrait = 2147483650;
    NSFontNameAttribute = "Avenir-Black";
    NSFontSizeAttribute = 14;
}
Index 2: {
    NSCTFontSymbolicTrait = 2147483651;
    NSFontNameAttribute = "Avenir-BlackOblique";
    NSFontSizeAttribute = 14;
}
```

However, the NSAttributedString itself remains completely un-changed. It is still the default Font. How can I get it to reflect the changes I am making to its attributes?

Comment: FYI - read the docs for `UIFontSymbolicTrait`. Note that it expects an `NSNumber` value, not an `NSString`.

Comment: This code works. The doc's are unreliable. I have tried adding it with the key "UIFontDescriptorTraitsAttribute" which does take an NSString, but it throws exceptions: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFontDescriptor_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Font_Attributes

For some reason, this 'incorrect' key is the only way I can add the traitsAttribute to the FontAttributes dictionary. Don't ask me why.

Comment: But you should be wrapping the value in `NSNumber`, not `NSString`. Such as `[fontAttributes setValue:@([fontDescriptor symbolicTraits]) forKey:UIFontSymbolicTrait];`.

Comment: @maddy You're right. I was confusing myself with UIFontDescriptorTraitsAttribute. I have fixed this, but it still has no effect on the outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

**1:** The documentation for `UIFontDescriptor` defines the key: `UIFontDescriptorNameAttribute` as an `NSString` instance, which it is.

**2:** The documentation for `NSAttributedString` defines the key: `NSFontAttributeName` as a `UIFont` instance.

So obtaining the `fontAttributes` dictionary from a `UIFontDescriptor` initialized with a the method: `(UIFontDescriptor *)fontDescriptorWithName:(NSString *)fontName size:(CGFloat)size` will only set the keys `UIFontDescriptorNameAttribute` and `UIFontDescriptorSizeAttribute`. If you wish to actually modify the font of an NSAttributedString however, you need to apply attributes with a UIFont instance saved to the key `NSFontAttributeName`.

This is where the confusion comes from. However, it should be noted that you can actually obtain `UIFontDescriptorNameAttribute` from the fontAttributes dictionary of a UIFontDescriptor instance with the key `NSFontAttributeName`. This may also be confusing.