# NSAttributedString with UIFontWeightTraits

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring, uifont, nsmutableattributedstring

I'm trying to generate a `NSAttributedString` that has basically just the default font, is italic and a different text color. Easy enough, so far.

Now I want different substrings of this entire string to *additionally* be bold. It should basically look like this:

*from **John Smith** on 25.08. at 8:00*

(Just in a different color.)

It looks like I'm getting the dictionary wrong, that I pass into the `NSMutableAttributedString`'s `addAttributes(_:_:)` function. From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFontDescriptor_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Font_Attributes), I understood that this dictionary should look like this:

```
[UIFontDescriptorTraitsAttribute: 
    [UIFontWeightTrait: NSNumber(double: Double(UIFontWeightBold))]
```

But this does not seem to work. All I end up with is the italic version of the string. I'm clearly getting something wrong here. Any idea?

*Update: Adding simple example*

```
// Preparation
let rawString = "from John Smith on 25.08. at 8:00"
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: rawString)
let nameRange = (rawString as NSString).rangeOfString("John Smith")
let italicFont = UIFont.italicSystemFontOfSize(14)

// Make entire string italic: works!
attributedString.addAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : italicFont], range: NSMakeRange(0, 33))
// Make the name string additionally bold: doesn't work!
attributedString.addAttributes([UIFontDescriptorTraitsAttribute:
        [UIFontWeightTrait: NSNumber(double: Double(UIFontWeightBold))]], range: nameRange)

// Show it on the label
attributedStringLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

Thanks!

Comment: You have to take multiple attribute strings and combine them to one to show.

Comment: You mean I can't add additional ones after the fact using the above mentioned function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIFontDescriptorTraitsAttribute` is not a recognized key in the `NSAttributedString` attributes dictionary, so having obtained the traits you need to reconstruct a `UIFont` and use the `NSFontAttributeName` key.

```
    //prepare the fonts. we derive the bold-italic font from the italic font
    let italicFont = UIFont.italicSystemFontOfSize(14)
    let italicDesc = italicFont.fontDescriptor()
    let italicTraits  = italicDesc.symbolicTraits.rawValue
    let boldTrait = UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits.TraitBold.rawValue
    let boldItalicTraits = UIFontDescriptorSymbolicTraits(rawValue:italicTraits | boldTrait)
    let boldItalicDescriptor = italicDesc.fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits(boldItalicTraits)
    let boldItalicFont = UIFont(descriptor: boldItalicDescriptor, size: 0.0)

    //prepare the string
    let rawString = "from John Smith on 25.08. at 8:00"
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: rawString)

    let fullRange = NSMakeRange(0, 33)
    let nameRange = (rawString as NSString).rangeOfString("John Smith")

    attributedString.addAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:italicFont], range: fullRange)
    attributedString.addAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:boldItalicFont], range: nameRange)
```

see also:[NSAttributedString: Setting FontAttributes doesn't change font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600861/nsattributedstring-setting-fontattributes-doesnt-change-font)

Comment: Awesome, thank you. This is what I was looking for. I remembered that I saw an approach like this before, but couldn't remember where or how it worked. Thanks!